# Writing alternate lists' elements - Python

Tags: python, list, formatting

I am trying to write alternating elements of multiple lists to a file using Python. I can write all of one list, and then all of another list, but am having difficulty doing it in an alternate order. My code looks like this:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bar = ['1', '2', '3']
fileout = open('zut.txt', 'w')
for i, el in foo, bar:
    fileout.write('%s\t%s' % (i, el))
```

However this produces a ValueError when I try and run it. For clarification, I am trying to produce a file like this:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a comment if you vote it down. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bar = ['1', '2', '3']
with open('zut.txt', 'w') as fileout:
    for x,y in zip(foo, bar):
        fileout.write('%s\t%s\n' % (x,y)) # you missed here '\n'
```

Read more about 'zip' and use 'with open...' to be sure that file will be automatically closed

Comment: Thankyou, I prefer this method as it scales up easier for me with many lists.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> zip(foo,bar)
[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

You can then iterate over the list and access the elements of the tuple.

```
>>> for tpl in zip(foo, bar):
...   print '%s\t%s' % tpl
...
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for letter, number in zip(foo, bar):
    fileout.write('%s\t\%s' % (letter, number))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `zip` function, to create that kind of 'corresponding' list, and then write it to file:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bar = ['1', '2', '3']

lst = zip(foo, bar)

with open('zut.txt', 'w') as f:
    for pair in lst:
        f.write( '{0}\t{1}'.format(pair[0], pair[1]) )
```